# Как связать модель через ForeignKey но только с определенными объектами таблицы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-model

имеется модель:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
```

и модель 2

```
class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255)
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table1.objects.filter(?))
```

Вопрос как к 2 модели дать возможность привязать только определенные объекты из `Table1`. Например объект можно привязать только, если у поле `name == 'a'` у первой модели. Есть такой функционал в Django?

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в функционале Джанго. Джанго своими моделями упрощает написание запросов в базу данных и может делать только то, что позволяют sql запросы. Скорее всего вам надо переосмыслить структуру вашей БД